# Relationship between the Penrose groupoid algebra and the group algebra of the symmetry group of a Penrose tiling

Tags: c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

[image]

Given a Penrose tiling, there are two C*-algebras associated with it: the $\mathcal{O}_\text{Penrose}$ algebra (Penrose groupoid algebra) and the group algebra of the symmetry group of the tiling, denoted by $\mathbb{C}[\text{Sym}(P)]$. What is the relationship between these two?

The Penrose groupoid algebra is constructed using the Penrose groupoid, which encodes the local symmetries of the tiling. The group algebra is constructed using the global symmetries of the tiling, generated by translations, rotations, and certain reflection symmetries that arise from the aperiodic nature of the tiling.

Perhaps, a bit more details are in order:

The Penrose groupoid is a small category whose objects are tiles in the Penrose tiling and whose morphisms are certain partial isometries between these tiles. The groupoid captures the local symmetries of the tiling, which are generated by a finite set of local moves (such as kite-and-dart substitutions) that transform one tile into another while preserving the overall pattern of the tiling. The $\mathcal{O}_\text{Penrose}$ algebra is then defined as the completion of the convolution algebra of complex-valued functions on the Penrose groupoid, using a suitable norm.

On the other hand, the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[\text{Sym}(P)]$ is generated by the elements of the symmetry group of the Penrose tiling, which consists of translations, rotations, and certain reflection symmetries that preserve the overall pattern of the tiling. The algebra $\mathbb{C}[\text{Sym}(P)]$ captures the global symmetries of the tiling, and is therefore a larger algebra than $\mathcal{O}_\text{Penrose}$.

QUESTION

Are there any deep connections between the $\mathcal{O}_\text{Penrose}$ algebra and $\mathbb{C}[\text{Sym}(P)]$? Are there any results that relate these two algebras, or that shed light on their similarities and differences?

References, insights, or suggestions for further reading are welcome. Thank you!

CODA

Perhaps the  $\mathcal{O}\text{Penrose}$ algebra can be viewed as a "quantum deformation" of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[\text{Sym}(P)]$, in the sense that it incorporates some noncommutative or quantum effects that arise from the aperiodic nature of the tiling. But I may be far off.